# Split a Circle Data Point Into Two

Tags: qgis, point

I am working with QGIS software to make a map of recorded temperatures at homes across a city. I have imported the data and represented it with dots at the specific locations and color coded them with a scale.

But now I would like to split those dots into two, to showcase on one side of the dot, the color representing the coldest temperature recorded at that point, and on the other side, the color representing the hottest temperature recorded at that point (kind of like the picture below).

Does anyone know how that could be done in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the existing symbol layer's Simple Marker type to a half circle and set the rotation to 90<sup>o</sup>

[image]

Add another symbol layer, set its marker type also to half circle but this time set the rotation to -90<sup>o</sup>

[image]